# How do you Edit where nested resource is involved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested, rails-activerecord

I am learning nested resources and am getting the following error when I try to edit an event. Event resources are nested under User resources. Any tips?

```
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Event with id=133 [WHERE "user_events"."user_id" = $1]
     # ./app/controllers/events_controller.rb:32:in `edit'
     # ./spec/features/user_edits_reg_info.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Events controller

```
def edit
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `Event` with id=133 does not belong to `current_user`, but a different user.

Assuming you're accessing this at a URL similar to `/users/1/events/133/edit`, you should be finding the user from the `:user_id` parameter (1 in my example) instead of using `current_user`:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @event = @user.events.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: That didn't work either. When I run my tests for creating events they are properly associated which I'd hope means it is true.